# Client-side Localization before loading template

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I work on my web app with **backbone.js** and **Marionette.js** extension.

For an international website, I want to make a localization module with async load of an appropriate JSON for a specific language (detected in client side with the browser language).

At the first load of main page, Marionette get all of template with an async method.

How can I replace language string before the Marionette template was rendered ?

Thanks for help and for understanding my English!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't anything Backbone specific of Marionette specific that you need to do. Any good JavaScript solution should work, and there's a great list of i18n resources for javascript in this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48726/best-javascript-i18n-techniques-ajax-dates-times-numbers-currency

Comment: Thanks Derick, I found https://github.com/jamuhl/i18next-webtranslate for my problem

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a plug and play solution that takes localization out of templates and does content management and translation service. I would recommend checking out Localize.js